# Does anybody know what this is?

Tags: diesel, john-deere, tractor

I was admiring my grandpa's John Deere 5203 tractor today and saw this. I'm pretty sure that's the throttle connected to the spring-hinge, so I'm guessing it's some kinda fuel injection. However, I know diesel engines strictly introduce fuel in the cylinder. So what is it, and what is its function? 
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Looks like it has a manufacturer and part number label on it.  Does that help?  Can't read anything other than "ADYNE" on it, but maybe you have a bigger or better picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This absolutely is the high pressure fuel injection pump for the diesel engine. I cannot tell for sure, but it looks as though this is a three cylinder engine (?) as I can only see two fuel lines coming out the right side of the injector pump. I'm assuming the third one is on the back side of this, behind the fuel line coming from the fuel tank (larger line in the middle). (NOTE: Actually, now that I'm looking closer, I can see the three lines which are linked together on the side of the block going upwards away from the pump.)

Comment: Yes it has 3 cylinders, which surprises me. Are all "high torque low hp" engines designed that way?

Comment: No. In actuality, when you say "high torque low hp", you are describing about every diesel engine out there. They tend to be that way, while gasoline engines tend to peak their hp at a higher rpm level. This is just a generality, as it all depends on how the engines are designed. If you are asking about the 3-cyl aspect, there are both gas and diesel engines with 3-cyl. Diesel engines can span from 3-cyl to 24-cyl and beyond (I don't believe I've seen any diesels with less than 3-cyl).

Comment: Okay, but what I was meaning to ask was,... Do utility/ farm tractors generally have a small amount of cylinders? Without looking I would've figured it'd have at least 6 if not 8.

Comment: It depends on whether gas or diesel, but 4 or less is very common with small tractors. Even medium size ones can have this. When you get into the larger tractors, 6-cyl diesels are probably the largest engines (cylinder wise) which you'll find. I've not dealt *too* much with them, but the ones I've seen all seem to follow this generality.